# Format codes for first page header/footer are different

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set a different header and footer with VBA for the first page of an Excel 2013 sheet that should be printed. The header and footer should contain information such as the page number, the name of the active sheet and the file name. The official Microsoft documentation about format codes (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/workbooks-and-worksheets/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers) provides various options for this, and all of those format codes work correctly on every page except for the first one - they appear to be assigned differently (e.g. "&N" should display the number of pages, but displays the file name instead) . How can I use the correct format codes for the first page header/footer?

I tried to assign those format codes to constants, but that doesn't work because the codes are only parsed when they are included in a header or footer string. I also recorded a macro while changing the headers manually (which works correctly), but that macro doesn't produce the correct output either.

```vb
Sub formatCodesTest()
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = "&N"
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
End Sub
```

I expected the output to be the number of pages (as it is described in the Microsoft docs), but the actual output is the file name.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Excel 2010 and 2013. It might be useful to know what version of Excel you are using.

Comment: works fine in 2016 as well, are you sure the header is blank. Did you check the custom header interface and ensure there are no &F

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I use Excel 2013. I tried this again with a new file & blank header, but the issue persists and the header GUI also shows "&[Datei]" (german for "&[File]") instead of "&[Seiten]" ("&[Pages]"). Could this be a locale problem? I also looked through all settings that seemed related, but haven't found anything that looks off.

Comment: I can confirm this bug for Excel 2019. I'm on the German locale, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have now managed to work around this problem. Instead of relying on the Microsoft documentation, enter the header/footer manually in the GUI and then use the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G) for debugging and query the contents of the relevant header (e.g. `? ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FirstPage.RightHeader.Text`). This will then give you the correct format codes.

If anybody else has an idea why this happens (and why others cannot reproduce it), I'll gladly accept this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Excel 2019: I wanted to show "Page 1 of 5" in the right footer.
As it concerns only the special settings for the first page, I solved it this way:

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = "Page 1 of " + Trim(Str(ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count))
```

Notice that this only works if filling cells, changing page layout, adding manual page breaks done by your VBA code is completed because before Excel can't now the correct amount of pages.